Problem with code tracking in Langsmith in Colab
I've just started with LangChain and Langsmith - so maybe this is silly, but I'm having trouble tracking the code in Langsmith in the following code (using Colab):
from langchain_core.documents import Document
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS
from langchain_openai import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings
import logging
from langchain.chains import create_retrieval_chain
from langsmith import Client


from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage, AIMessage
from langchain_core.prompts import MessagesPlaceholder



def get_document_from_web(url):
  logging.getLogger("langchain_text_splitters.base").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
  loader = WebBaseLoader(url)
  docs = loader.load()
  splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
      chunk_size=400,
      chunk_overlap=20
      )
  splitDocs = splitter.split_documents(docs)
  return splitDocs



def create_db(docs):
    embeddings = AzureOpenAIEmbeddings(
        model="text-embedding-3-large",
        azure_endpoint="https://langing.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/Embed-test/embeddings?api-version=2023-05-15",
        openai_api_key="xxx",
        openai_api_version="2023-05-15"
    )
    vectorStore = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
    return vectorStore

def create_chain(vectorStore):
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
        ("system", "Answet the quistion based on the following context: {context}"),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
        ("human", "{input}")
    ])




    chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm=model,
                                     prompt=prompt)

    retriever = vectorStore.as_retriever(search_kwargs = {"k":3})
    retriever_chain = create_retrieval_chain(
        retriever,
        chain
    )
    return retriever_chain

def process_chat(chain, question,chat_history):
  response = chain.invoke({
    "input": question,
    "chat_history": chat_history
    })
  return response["answer"]

chat_history = []


if __name__ == "__main__":
  docs =get_document_from_web("https://docs.smith.langchain.com/evaluation/concepts")
  vectoreStore = create_db(docs)
  chain = create_chain(vectoreStore)
  while True:
    user_input = input("You: ")
    if user_input.lower() == "exit":
        break
    response = process_chat(chain, user_input, chat_history)
    chat_history.append(HumanMessage(content= user_input))
    chat_history.append(AIMessage(content = response))
    print("Bot:", response)

Everything is runing well but I do not see logs in Langsmith, does anyone have any idea why?
I tried everything I could find, but with no result.
Thanks a looot for any tips.
